# ORMLite foreign collection and serialization

Tags: serialization, ormlite, foreign-collection

How to send an object with ORMLite `ForeignCollection` between two activities ? Is that `ForeignCollection` is non serializable ? I'm getting the `IOException` which is due to non serializable object.

Ex: in My Call class

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
private transient ForeignCollection<CallObjective> _callObjectives;
```

in My CallObjective class:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "CallId", foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private Call _call;
```

Comment: Did my answer help you @Rakhita?  Be sure to upvote it and accept it if it did.  If you don't accept answers then there is no reason for folks to answer your questions.  Best of luck!

Comment: I'm really sorry for not up-voting, I was bit busy yesterday, thank you very much for your information. But it didn't help to overcome my issue. I'm working to get it done in a different methodology...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 4.26 of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) we made some improvements to the `EagerForeignCollection` class to make it more serializable.  I found a bug in trunk the other day actually that [unfortunately] stops the `LazyForeignCollection` class which you are using with the `eager = false` from being serializable.  That will be fixed in version 4.28.

Even if the collection was serializable, you would not be able to do anything with the lazy collections because there is too much context to be able to deserialize it properly.  It will be a shell that throws exceptions on most operations.

Comment: works all fine with version 4.29 of ORMLite. Gray, thank you for your suggestion and comments.